# lucene.net match if search term has no space

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using lucene.net to perform searchs in posts in my c# asp.net application, This is a sample document in my indexes:

```
var doc = new Document();
var title = new Field("Title", "the album hardwired to self-destruct released", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS);
title.Boost = 5;
doc.Add(title);
var ns_title = new Field("NoSpace_Title", "thealbumhardwiredtoselfdesctructreleased", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS);
ns_title.Boost = 5;
doc.Add(ns_title);
doc.Add(new Field("Body", "the body text of the post", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
doc.Add(new Field("Id", "1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

**Problem**:
if I search for `self` or `destruct` or `self destruct` I get hit.
if I search for `selfdestruct` I dont get a hit.

**The search method**:

```
var searchWords = s.Split(' ').ToList();
var directory = GetDirectory();
var reader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Title,NoSpace_Title,Body".Split(','), analyzer);
var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

// Title:selfdestruct*NoSpace_Title:selfdestruct*Body:selfdestruct*
s = string.Join(" ", searchWords.Select(x => x.Contains("*") ? x : x + "*"));
Query query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(s));
query.Boost = 5;
booleanQuery.Add(query, Occur.SHOULD);

// Title:*selfdestruct*,NoSpace_Title:*selfdestruct*,Body:*selfdestruct*
// (I suppose this should work and get hit but it doesn't)
s = "*" + string.Join("", searchWords) + "*";
Query query2 = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(s));
query2.Boost = 3;
booleanQuery.Add(query2, Occur.SHOULD);

// Title:selfdestruct~0.85 (fuzzy search)
s = string.Join(" ", searchWords.Select(x => x.Contains("~") ? x : x + "~0.85"));
Query query3 = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(s));
booleanQuery.Add(query3, Occur.SHOULD);

var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(1000, true);
searcher.Search(booleanQuery, collector);
var hits = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
var docs = hits.Select(x => searcher.Doc(x.Doc)).ToList();
```

Comment: what is the analyzer you are using while indexing ?

Comment: @root545 I'm using same when I searching, `StandardAnalyzer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can support this by adding a [ShingleFilter](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d7/deb/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_shingle_1_1_shingle_filter.html) into your analyzer.

ShingleFilter will combine adjacent tokens into single tokens to facilitate searching for them without a space. By default, it will output Unigrams as well (that is, it will also maintain the single tokens).  So, when you index "self-destruct", it will index the tokens "self", "destruct", and "selfdestruct".

An easy way to do this without creating your own custom analyzer, is to use [ShingleAnalyzerWrapper](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d5/da5/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_shingle_1_1_shingle_analyzer_wrapper.html):

```
var analyzer = new ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(
        new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30),
        2);
```

Comment: I read ShingleFilter.cs documents, it says: 
For example, the sentence "please divide this sentence into shingles" might be tokenized into shingles "please divide", "divide this", "this sentence", "sentence into", and "into shingles".
I think I need something similar, I mean something that attach words together. for example: `pleasedivide`, `dividethis`, `thissentence`, `sentenceinto`, and `intoshingles`

Comment: I used `ShingleFilter` as suggested by femtoRgon with one minor modification which was changing `TOKEN_SEPARATOR = " "` to `string.empty`. marked as answer.